# showing the formulas but not the values in Open Office Calc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

Normally a spreadsheet hides the formulas you enter and displays the values. I'm looking for a way to display the formulas but hide the values, so I can print it out and show people how my spreadsheet actually does what it does. Any ideas?

Comment: I answered my own question... see below!

Comment: Then you should mark as closed.

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2350/openoffice_org_calc_show_formulas/

1. Click Tools and select Options.
2. In the left pane of the Options window, expand OpenOffice.org Calc.
3. Select View.
4. In the Display section, check the Formulas checkbox.
5. Click OK.

Comment: There is no Tools --> Options in Open Office 4.x !

Answer (score 0):

You need to input the Formula using the Address Bar. Even formula checkbox is not selection in options, if you type a formula starting with "=" sign on the sheet other than use of existing functions this issue will happen.
Simply follow these steps

1. Select the target cell or first cell in the range
2. Click on Formula icon in Formula Bar. It will insert an '=' sign in the bar
3. Now type your formula in the formula Bar and Press Enter / Click Green tick icon